# Detecting Specific Sounds (Frequencies) with Python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, fft, aubio

I want to record sound of a machine and want to detect if its present in another sound file that I record.
I am able to record the sound of the machine and the sound file that I want to detect its presence.

I am also able to take fft of the sound files, however I dont know If I should check specific frequencies or check it in time intervals. 
Can I implement it with aubio or is there another way?

[silent room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFdnl.png)
[silent room + sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU6Xo.png)

Comment: What is the machine that you are recording? Do you mean the very same record of the machine or record of the same machine?

Comment: Record of same machine. I want to detect the source of the noises in the room automatically. So in a room first I record a sound in wav format. There were no dominant noise exist (assume silent), next I record a specific noise (caused by audio jack from speaker). Now I will write a program which records sounds in a determined interval, then check if the noise (audio jack noise) exist or not. So in basic; how can I compare 2 wav file and figure out the additional sound?

Comment: If you neglect the reflections, you should create a noise signature and compare it the your reference. This task is not trivial and requires solid knowledge in many fields. 
To understand how such signature can characterize, I suggest you to review the following work:
Antoni, Jérôme. "Cyclostationarity by examples." Mechanical Systems and Signal Processing 23.4 (2009): 987-1036.
Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Since this only a small part of my project, I thoughed that I could compare two sound files with aubio or any python application. Is it possible or there is no such application to do that?

Comment: I am not familiar with such a program. Maybe you should reconsider your project content or reevaluate the time you want to dedicate for this section.